# Initializing a vector of structs takes large compile time

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, constructor, initialization

I'm writing a program in C++11, which analyses chess positions and computes some interesting statistics. The data I'm loading in is formatted into a structure

```
struct board{
  board(long int hash1,long int hash2);
};
```

and I'm storing everything in another structure

```
struct data_struct{
  vector<board> allboards;
  void read_data(char* filename);
  //other member functions
};
```

Previously I was reading in data from a text file, but I'm working on a computer cluster where file I/O is expensive and I have to execute the same program many times with different settings but the same data. So I figured it would be more efficient to hard-code the data and overload the default constructor for data_struct. So in a separate source file I have a constructor

```
data_struct::data_struct(){
  allboards.push_back(board(2315678,6235756));
  allboards.push_back(board(464135138,1563135));
  \\5000 more lines like this 
}
```

The numbers don't matter, they are hashed representations of board states. My problem is that **compiling this code takes very long**. I think the problem is that I'm calling the constructor for board 5000 times, because if I hard-code just the hashes as arrays instead, compilation takes no more than a couple seconds. However, then the program has to convert these arrays into a vector at execution time, which is inelegant and wastes memory as well as time. Is there an elegant way to solve this, for example using initialization lists?

Edit: I'm compiling using Mingw-w64 with -O3 and -fexpensive-optimizations enabled. It doesn't get faster without the optimizations.

Comment: Just to clarify; is the problem compiling the program or running the program?  If it's slow running try calling reserve() giving a count on the expected size.

Comment: The problem is compile time. It's not huge, but it's over a minute and it's slowing me down quite significantly when developing/debugging the code.

Comment: Could you show the code where you create the `data_struct` variables? Are you compiling with inlining enabled? The compiler may be trying to resolve the constructor calls at compile-time.

Comment: 40KB of file I/O is expensive?!

Comment: @David Schwartz, I'm running this program between thousands and tens of thousands of times, so it adds up. Also, it's annoying to keep dragging text files around, putting it in the compiler makes the code nice and portable. Plus, I'm trying to become a better programmer, so learning the 'correct' way to do this would be nice :)

Comment: @Neil Kirk, not sure what code you mean. The read_data function just consists of a large for-loop which reads the hashed numbers from a text file and constructs the vector the same way using allboards.push_back(board(hash1,hash2)).

Comment: Where is `data_struct x;` and what is the code?

Comment: In main.cpp: `int main(int argc, char* argv[]){ data_struct x;
compute_statistics(x); return 0;}`

I'm skipping a large part of the code here, but essentially I'm just making the object, then passing it (by reference) to some other functions which do the work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ 11? I would replace your data_struct constructor

```
data_struct::data_struct(){
  allboards.emplace_back(2315678, 6235756);
  allboards.emplace_back(464135138, 1563135);
  \\5000 more lines like this 
}
```

... as a cheapest solution. It could have cut compiler time to some extents and definitely should help run time to get faster.

And for even better improvement it makes sense for you to consider [initialization list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) so that you just supply all these numbers in as many pairs as you want but that requires significant redo for data_struct constructor. Look at the subject below... You may eventually want to convert that to

```
data_struc someChessData;
someChessData.allboards =
{
{2315678, 6235756},
{464135138, 1563135},
...,
{more_n1, more_n2}
};
```

Update: of course initialization list, I made the fix above, just try assigning allboards with such construct.

Comment: Why do you think emplace_back would compile faster than push_back?

Comment: I'm relatively new to C++11, so I don't have much experience with initialization lists. What is the cleanest way to initialize a vector of structs (especially with compile-time in mind)?

Comment: Since the all_boards is a std::vector (which is a template), each push_back() call is spitting out some code taking time to compile.  Shouldn't be much though, unless it compiling as debug mode.  The init list should be cheap though.

Comment: @NeilKirk I suppose it could slightly decrease parsing time, but Idk if it matters on the scale of 1000s of lines

Comment: Great! Switching to emplace_back() did speed the compilation process up by a factor 3. I'll try the initialisation list next.

Comment: basvanopheusden, try initalizaition list as well, I made a change above. That should work as well. And you can combine that with static initialization as well. Agree on static.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works really well! The emplace() method is a lot faster to compile, the initialization list takes longer to compile, but the code is really clean so I actually prefer that.

Answer (score 1):

If the data are constant, I recommend using a `static` `const` array of `struct`s.

The array will be initialized before `main` usually in the most efficient manner.  The compiler could create a data table and your code access the data table directly.

If you really need a vector, you can construct a vector from the array.