# Does vector emplace compile faster than push_back?

Tags: c++, c++11

While `emplace` can have run-time benefits, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26953649/3758484) suggests it can also speed up compilation. [This fellow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26953394/initializing-a-vector-of-structs-takes-large-compile-time/26953649#comment42447644_26953649) agrees.

Why is that?

Comment: I very much doubt anybody can give an educated estimate of compilation speed of `push_back` vs `emplace`.

Comment: @SergeyA i agree, but the reasoning proposed by those answerers just doesn't make any meaningful sense to me.

Comment: emplace can have faster runtime performance. Don't know anything about compilation times. I doubt it has any meaningful impact.

Comment: That question was parsing `\\5000 more lines like this` of code. I suspect the 5000 lines was a bigger determining factor in compounding the parse/compile of the `push_back` vs `emplace_back`. Any different *5000 will be reasonable.

Comment: [Which is faster?](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Those two users have been members for well over 6 years, participated in highly frequented tags (Java/C++) and still barely made 4k reputation. That often indicates less trustworthy sources of information. Both the answer as well as the comment would very much fit into that picture (why would a `push_back` call on a template spit out more code than an `emplace_back` call on a template?)

Comment: @IInspectable cause `push_back()` calls `emplace_back()`?

Comment: @IInspectable Also by that logic, [Herb Sutter](http://stackoverflow.com/users/297582/herb-sutter) isn't trustworthy either.

Comment: @Barry, I think, what matters here is a karma-to-posts ratio, not the time spent as a memeber. And the ratio of those two users is not that great.

Comment: @Barry: Just check with several C++ Standard Library implementations, picked at random. Neither one called `emplace_back` from `push_back`. I don't see anything in the C++ Language Specification that would mandate this either.

Comment: @IInspectable gcc does, for one.

Comment: @Barry: That's not really relevant. If this is not a specified, mandatory feature, you cannot state it like it were a fact. It's an implementation detail, that at least one author subscribed to.

Comment: @SergeyA An answer is either correct or incorrect. Its correctness does not depend on a user's other answers' correctness. There's no need for ad hominem.

Comment: @Barry, let's say someone makes a statement which runs against all I know, in fact, I am sure I tested it 15 minutes ago and it gave the results I would expect. Now, if it would be someone I learned to respect from other statements made, I would certainly engage in the discussion. If it would be some schmuck, I would ignore. This is just the human nature - authority makes words matter more.

Comment: So, have you tried it?

Comment: Oh god - who knew I was untrustworthy as I only answer stuff here now and then as my job allows.  Hows 6 years here with only 9k karma.  I feel like such a luser. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There many questions here since you are comparing `emplace`, `push_back` and `construction` during run-time and compilation.  Let's take compilation first.

Compilation involves translation the source code into assembly instructions.  Before emitting any assembly instructions there are usually 2 phases:  lexing and parsing.  The lexing is checking syntax and the parsing is checking and handling semantics (again, this is very simplified).

Given the two statements:

```
my_vector.push_back(value);
my_vector.emplace(value);
```

The work required to scan, parse and evaluate should be nearly identical.  Thus there should not be any differences in compilation times.

Also, with the processing speed of most compilers, if there is a difference in compilation times, it is negligible compared to the time starting the compiler *and the time performing I/O*.  At best, I would expect saving a millisecond.  If you have over 1000 of these you may save a second of compilation time.  Human reaction time to the compiler finishing is more than 1 second.  Thus the savings is still negligible or not worthwhile.

As far as run-time goes, you would have to profile.  Let's say for example that `emplace` is 1 ms faster than `push_back`.  You would need to execute over 1000 `emplace` functions to gain 1 second (if your program is continuously running and not interrupted).  You would need to execute over 60000 to save a minute.  All this savings may be lost by waiting for I/O or other tasks to finish.  More likely, you'll be saving nanoseconds, not milliseconds.

Focus your efforts on correct and robust code.  Only worry about optimizations after your program is correct and has no faults and doesn't crash.  Only optimize if the User says its slow, it doesn't meet critical timing events or it doesn't fit in memory.  Think about how much code you could have written in the time you are contemplating this micro-optimization.